# Drawing on a canvas a big pixels

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, drawing

I am writing an app which allow user to draw on a touch screen display. I am currently using the method below and it work very well.  This method is producing a “high resolution image” since for almost every single pixel a line is drawn (e.g. 100, 100 -> 102, 103).

Here is my question. I’d like user to draw a “low resolution picture” (big pixels board) where you can intentionally see pixels of 50×50 (e.g. 100, 100 -> 150, 150). Does anybody have an idea on how to accomplish that? I am using Silverlight for Windows Phone. I was thinking about building a big grid of 50×50 pixels, but there might be too many controls.

```
void FingerMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsDrawing)
    {
        this.DestinationPoint = e.GetPosition(paint);
        Line line = new Line
        {
            Stroke = this.Color,
            X1 = this.DestinationPoint.X,
            Y1 = this.DestinationPoint.Y,
            X2 = this.OriginPoint.X,
            Y2 = this.OriginPoint.Y,
            StrokeStartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
            StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
            StrokeThickness = 15,
            Opacity = 1,
        };

        Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(",", line.X1, line.Y1, line.X2, line.Y2));

        paint.Children.Add(line);
    }

    this.OriginPoint = this.DestinationPoint;
}
```

Comment: before rendering to screen, draw to a backbuffer (off screen bitmap) then scale to another with dimensions x and y 50 times too small, then upscale to finally draw on screen, all with no interpolation.

Comment: Are you saying you want to see a blocky line, or a line that conforms to a grid?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Yes, this is what I want.

Comment: @Martin, which one, do you want a pixelated image, or do you want to draw smooth lines, that 'snap to grid'?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: I want a pixelated drawing which snap to a 'virtual' grid of 50x50 pixels.

Comment: Instead of drawing a line, draw rectangles 50x50. divide the users position by 50 then multiply by 50 (integer division/multiplication) to get it to snap to grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Amr has the right idea.  I'll give you this code with the caveat that I haven't tested it at all.  I took the line segment intersection algorithm from [here](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/lineline2d/).

First, you need to set up a list of Rectangles and add them to the canvas that are your "pixels":

```
    private List<Rectangle> _rects = new List<Rectangle>();

    private void GenerateRects()
    {
        int width = 300; // or whatever dimensions...
        int height = 300;
        int gridSize = 50;

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x += gridSize)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y += gridSize)
            {
                var rect = new Rectangle
                {
                    Opacity = 0,
                    Width = Math.Min(gridSize, width - x),
                    Height = Math.Min(gridSize, height - y),
                };

                Canvas.SetLeft(rect, x);
                Canvas.SetTop(rect, y);

                _rects.Add(rect);
                this.paint.Children.Add(rect);
            }
        }
    }
```

We'll need these helper methods:

```
    class LineSegment
    {
        public double X1 { get; set; }
        public double X2 { get; set; }
        public double Y1 { get; set; }
        public double Y2 { get; set; }
    }

    private static bool SegmentsIntersect(LineSegment A, LineSegment B)
    {
        double x1 = A.X1, x2 = A.X2, x3 = B.X1, x4 = B.X2;
        double y1 = A.Y1, y2 = A.Y2, y3 = B.Y1, y4 = B.Y2;

        double denominator = (y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1);

        if (denominator == 0)
            return false;

        double ua = ((x4 - x3) * (y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3) * (x1 - x3)) / denominator;
        double ub = ((x2 - x1) * (y1 - y3) - (y2 - y1) * (x1 - x3)) / denominator;

        return (ua > 0 && ua < 1 && ub > 0 && ub < 1);
    }

    private static bool RectIntersectsLine(Rect A, LineSegment B)
    {
        return (SegmentsIntersect(B, new LineSegment { X1 = A.X, Y1 = A.Y, X2 = A.X, Y2 = A.Y + A.Height }) ||
            SegmentsIntersect(B, new LineSegment { X1 = A.X, Y1 = A.Y + A.Height, X2 = A.X + A.Width, Y2 = A.Y + A.Height }) ||
            SegmentsIntersect(B, new LineSegment { X1 = A.X + A.Width, Y1 = A.Y + A.Height, X2 = A.X + A.Width, Y2 = A.Y }) ||
            SegmentsIntersect(B, new LineSegment { X1 = A.X + A.Width, Y1 = A.Y, X2 = A.X, Y2 = A.Y }) ||
            RectContainsPoint(A, new Point(B.X1, B.Y1)) ||
            RectContainsPoint(A, new Point(B.X2, B.Y2)));
    }

    private static bool RectContainsPoint(Rect A, Point B)
    {
        return (B.X > A.X && B.X < A.X + A.Width && B.Y > A.Y && B.Y < A.Y + A.Height);
    }
```

Then, in the FingerMove function, we loop through each Rectangle to see if it intersects.  If it does, we change its color:

```
    void FingerMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsDrawing)
        {
            this.DestinationPoint = e.GetPosition(paint);
            LineSegment line = new LineSegment
            {
                X1 = this.DestinationPoint.X,
                Y1 = this.DestinationPoint.Y,
                X2 = this.OriginPoint.X,
                Y2 = this.OriginPoint.Y
            };

            foreach (var rect in _rects)
            {
                var x = Canvas.GetLeft(rect);
                var y = Canvas.GetTop(rect);

                if (RectIntersectsLine(new Rect(x, y, rect.Width, rect.Height) , line))
                {
                    rect.Opacity = 1;
                    rect.Fill = Color;
                }
            }
        }

        this.OriginPoint = this.DestinationPoint;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to make the line thicker, just experiment with possible values of StrokeThickness untill you get the desired effect.

If you want to manually draw the line by filling up large areas of the screen say (50x50) rectangles, you could do the follwing:

1. divide the screen into 50x50 rectangles
2. check which rectangles are intersected by the line drawn by the user
3. only draw the rectangles from step 2

This would give you the 'snap to grid' line that you want.